# Find the best way for combination without repetition calculation in swift

Tags: swift, math, factorial

I'd like to find best swift solution for this kind of mathematic question:

> Assume having 5 people in the room. Everybody have to shake hands to
>   each other. How many combinations does it bring?

While I know the combination formula

[image]

and I use this swift factorial func:

```
func factorial(n: Int) -> Int {
    return n == 0 ? 1 : n * factorial(n — 1)
}
```

Is there a way to establish a function, that counts combinations not by only replacing variables in the above formula?

NOTE:

I don't think this is the most optimised way:

```
let combinations = factorial(n: 5)/(factorial(n: 2)*factorial(n: 3)) // 10
```

Comment: Strictly spoken the factorial function **does** count due to the recursion ;)

Comment: I mean I am looking for the way other than replacing formula like 'factorial(n:5) / factorial(n:2) / factorial(n:3)' .

Comment: This one @Martin R: http://pasteboard.co/gv1WgOnY1.png. It is a swift question, as I want to find better solution to apply my func into that formula.

Comment: `func handshakes(n: Int) -> Int { return n*(n-1)/2 }` – Is that what you are looking for? Sorry, I honestly do not understand your question.

Comment: @MartinR I see your formula returns the right result. It looks pretty. I was looking for a solution that omits using recursive factorial func. Thanks! Is this question supposed to be answered by common answer post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of ways to choose `k` items from `n` is given by
the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) `C(n, k)`.
The [multiplicative formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Multiplicative_formula)
for nonnegative `n` and `k` can be implemented in Swift as

```
/// Binimomial coefficient C(n, k) for non-negative integers n, k.
func binomial(n: Int, _ k: Int) -> Int {
    precondition(k >= 0 && n >= 0)
    if (k > n) { return 0 }
    var result = 1
    for i in 0 ..< min(k, n-k) {
        result = (result * (n - i))/(i + 1)
    }
    return result
}
```

This is "better" than the formula using factorials

```
C(n, k) = n! / (k! * (n-k)!)
```

in the sense that the intermediate values do not become so large.
(But it *can* overflow, for example

```
C(70, 35) = 112186277816662845432
```

exceeds the range of 64-bit integers!)

Example ([Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle)):

```
for n in 0...7 {
    print((0...n).map { k in binomial(n, k) })
}

// Output:
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 3, 3, 1]
[1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
[1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1]
[1, 6, 15, 20, 15, 6, 1]
[1, 7, 21, 35, 35, 21, 7, 1]
```

In your special case, the number of handshakes between `n` 
persons is `C(n, 2) = n*(n-1)/2`. You can compute that with above
function or just with

```
func handshakes(n: Int) -> Int {
    return n*(n-1)/2
}
```